# PIG filter out rows with improper number of columns

Tags: apache-pig, filtering

I have simple data loaded in **a**:

```
dump a

ahoeh,1,e32
hello,2,10
ho,3
```

I need to filter out all rows with number of columns/fields different than 3. How to do it?
In other words result should be:

```
dump results

ahoeh,1,e32
hello,2,10
```

I know there should be a FILTER built-in function. However I cannot figure out what condition (number of columns =3) should be defined.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

**input**

```
ahoeh,1,e32
hello,2,10
ho,3
3,te,0
aa,3,b
y,h,3
3,3,3
3,3,3,1,2,3,3,,,,,,4,44,6
```

**PigScript1:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line,','));
C = FOREACH B GENERATE COUNT(TOBAG(*)),$0..;
D = FILTER C BY $0==3;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE $1..;
DUMP E;
```

**PigScript2:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',');
B = FOREACH A GENERATE COUNT(TOBAG(*)),$0..;
C = FILTER B BY (int)$0==3;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE $1..;
DUMP D;
```

**Output:**

```
(ahoeh,1,e32)
(hello,2,10)
(3,te,0)
(aa,3,b)
(y,h,3)
(3,3,3)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as you are checking if the content of one of the fields matches '3'.

Comment: @xhudik,  initially i misunderstood your question, here the updated solution, it will work irrespective of any number of columns. Please take a look.

Comment: @LiMuBei, I misunderstood the question. thanks for pointing out the problem. I have updated the right solution now, please take a look and remove the downvote if my answer convinced you.

Comment: Looks much better now. I think you could get rid of the `FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line,','))` if you specify comma as separator for the PigStorage when loading. `A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',');`

Comment: yes this is it @SivasakthiJayaraman . Final question: how can I get rid of warning: "[main] WARN  org.apache.pig.PigServer - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_LONG 1 time(s)." ?

Comment: @xhudik, Can you explicitly typecast  the $0 variable as long in the filter stmt.    D = FILTER C BY (long)$0==3;.  After that also if the warning exist find the right place and do the explicit typecast with long.  I have updated one more solution in that i didnt see any warning. please check it.

Answer (score 1):

*(It seems that I don't have enough karma to comment; that's why this is posted as a new answer.)*

The accepted answer doesn't quite behave as expected if null/empty string is a valid field value; you need to use `COUNT_STAR` instead of `COUNT` to count empty/null fields in your schema.

See: https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#count-star

For example, given the following input data:

```
1,2,3
1,,3
```

and this Pig script:

```
a = load 'input' USING PigStorage(',');
counted = foreach a generate COUNT_STAR(TOBAG(*)), $0..;
filtered = filter counted by $0 != 3;
result = foreach filtered generate $1..;
```

The `filtered` alias will contain both rows. The difference is that `COUNT({(1),(),(3)})` returns `2` while `COUNT_STAR({(1),(),(3)})` returns `3`.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to do this:
First, you can rephrase the filter I think, as it boils down to: Give me all lines that do not contain an NULL value. For lots of columns, writing this filter statement is rather tedious.

Second, you could convert your columns into a bag per line, using TOBAG (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/func.html#tobag) and then write a UDF that processes the input bag to check for null tuples in this bag and return true or false and use this in the filter statement.

Either way, some tediousness is required I think.